# maven: specify settings.xml location in pom

Tags: maven, build, settings

**Requirement**: we need the central control over settings.xml for some portion of it for example mirror configuration

and some of the sections needs to be user specific [for example: credentials]

So the idea is to put the common settings.xml under source control (for example: svn) and configure parent pom so that it can take the common settings.xml at location (for example `${user.home}/abc/def/settings.xml`)

and we need to include user specific settings.xml for some of the user specific things

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to put repo settings, as well as for example profile settings, into [parent pom directly](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories), so you wouldn't need to think about settings.xml there (though it doesn't seem to be possible for mirror configuration). However, the recommended solution would be using a repository manager like Nexus or Artifactory to be in control of repo settings, and user only pointing to the repository manager. That's the way to have central control over the configuration, not settings.xml.

Comment: could you please elaborate little more how can I put mirror in pom.xml, I don't see that on link

Comment: @JigarJoshi you're right, it doesn't allow you to set mirror config there, only repositories. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

The formal [Maven Settings Reference](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html) inform us as the following: -

> The settings element in the settings.xml file contains elements used to define values which configure Maven execution in various ways, like the pom.xml, but **should not be bundled** to *any specific project*, or *distributed to an audience*. These include values such as the local repository location, alternate remote repository servers, and ***authentication information***.

There are 2 useful links for further information as the following: -

1.[Injecting POM Properties via Settings.xml](http://maven.apache.org/examples/injecting-properties-via-settings.html)

2.[Using Mirrors for Repositories](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html)

I always use the settings.xml together with POM as the following example: -

### settings.xml

```
  <properties>
      <svnHost>https://myhost/svn/</svnHost>
      <svnUser>the user id</svnUser>
      <svnPassword>the password</svnPassword>
  </properties>
```

#### pom.xml

```
<scm>
    <connection>
        scm:svn:${svnHost}/${project.artifactId}/trunk
    </connection>
    <developerConnection>
        scm:svn:${svnHost}/${project.artifactId}/trunk
    </developerConnection>
    <url>...</url>
</scm>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${my.maven.scm.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <username>${svnUser}</username>
        <password>${svnPassword}</password>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I hope this may help and give you an idea.

Comment: The usuage of placeholders like ${svnHost} in SCM will only work temporarily untill the first time you do a release via Maven release plugin.

Comment: +1 to @khmarbaise. pom.xml is designed to work standalone, so introducing a dependency you're breaking Maven guidelines.